# How to send and receive a file in SocketCAN or Python-can?

Tags: python, socketcan, python-can

I want to send a text file from one serial device(slcan0) to another serial device(slcan1) can this operation be performed in SocketCAN? The serial CAN device I am using is CANtact toolkit. Or can the same operation be done in Python-can?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to send a text file over the CAN bus, you have to decide which CAN-ID you want so sent for sending and receiving.

Most likely your text file is larger than 8 bytes, so you would have to use a higher level protocol on CAN.
ISO-TP will allow 4095 of data in one message.
If this is still not enough, you would have to invent another protocol for sending and receiving the data. E.g. first send the length of data, then send the data in chunks of 4095 bytes.

Once you have figured this out, it does not really matter whether you use SocketCAN, Python-CAN, pyvit or anything else.